Define a static async create function has same parameters with constructor
I have many classes already written that need to be refactored to use an async constructor.
For example:
class ClassA {
    constructor(a: number, b: string, c: string) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}

I added an async create method:
class ClassA {

    // added async 
    static async create(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof ClassA>){
        await loadSameResources()
        return new this(...args)
    }

    constructor(a: number, b: string, c: string) {
        //...
    }
}

It works fine, users just need to change new ClassA(...) to (await ClassA.create(...)), it's simple and keeps the necessary modification small.
My problem is how to avoid to write 'ClassA' in the create function, something like below so I can copy this function in every class (I can't modify class inheritance)
    // added async 
    static async create(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof this>){ // error here
        await loadSameResources()
        return new this(...args)
    }


Despite the problem itself, is it worthwhile to keep the constructor exposed? one could instantiate the class via new, losing the nominal way through the create.

@MarioVernari constructor is  private in real world ,i make it public for simpler in question,  i use type CtorParameters<T> = ConstructorParameters<{ new (): never } & T>; to replace ConstructorParameters, it's from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30991#issuecomment-1543408212

okay, but at that point, why using the ctor? just define your args for the create method and stop. Please, tell me if I'm missing the point.

@MarioVernari i want make the change small ,so i don't change the constructor  at all

An asynchronous constructor is a smell. The constructor should not do work. All it should do is to initialise the object using the values passed to it as arguments. The static "constructor" that you created is, in fact, a factory function that does not belong to the class. Extract it in a separate module and you have a clean design. Don't waste time trying to force TypeScript do syntactical gimmicks. Focus on the code behaviour.

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz ,it's great! another problem is  loadSameResources need a resourcePath depend ClassA , i try create a CreateGen to return create function , but no luck ,check tsplay

That seems like a followup question (because your original didn't pass anything to loadSameResources() or even define it). May I go ahead and answer your question as asked and if you can't figure out your next problem you open a new question for it?

While changing your target semantics, you could very simply make a generic function to build your instances:
import { Constructor } from 'type-fest'

async function create<TInstance>(Class: Constructor<TInstance>, ...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Class>) {
    await loadSameResources()
    return new Class(...args)
}

const a = await create(ClassA, 0, 'b', 'c')
//    ^? const a: ClassA

Playground Link
Advantages:

The create function is defined in a single place (much easier to maintain)
No need to change anything to your current classes


Another possibility, which would preserve your target semantics ((await ClassA.create(...))), but slightly more verbose, would consist in using a Class Mixin:
function WithCreateMixin<TInstance extends object>(BaseClass: Constructor<TInstance>) {
    return class BaseClassWithCreate extends BaseClass {
        static async create(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof BaseClass>) {
            await loadSameResources()
            return new BaseClass(...args)
        }
    }
}

class ClassA extends WithCreateMixin(class ClassA0 {
    constructor(a: number, b: string, c: string) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}) { }

const a = await ClassA.create(0, 'b', 'c')
//    ^? const a: ClassA0

Playground Link
The create static function is still defined in a single place, but now you need to wrap your existing classes (with class ClassX extends WithCreateMixin(/* original class */) { }).

You could do something like make the constructor call a private initializer function, for which it's much easier to extract parameters.
class ClassA {

    // added async 
    static async create(...args: Parameters<typeof this.prototype.init>){
        await loadSameResources(() => {})
        return new this(...args)
    }

    constructor(...args: Parameters<typeof this.init>) {
        this.init(...args)
    }

    private init(a: number, b: string, c: string) {}
}

Making all of your classes' constructor call the private init function makes it easy for both the constructor and the create function to infer their own parameter types from this init function.
You can now copy/paste both create and constructor to each of your classes with no modification.
As other users suggested, you might also want to make the constructor private if you have no need to expose it.

@xt-z it's not ok to ask questions and then ignore responses. We took time out of our days because we wanted to help you out, and the least you can do is leave some feedback to say if the answers were helpful or not.
